# Xcode mouse and NSView basic help?

Tags: xcode, click, mouse, nsview

I am making an app for school and I would love to change the cursor picture when the mouse is clicked in a certain NSView area.

I know that you can use mousedown, mouseup and other events, but I don't really know how to put them in my code in order for the cursor picture change to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the custom NSView and override resetCursorRect, 
Refer the example code below

```
-(void)resetCursorRects{

    //[self log:@"Inside Reset Cursor Rect"];
    NSRect viewRect = [self frame];// change it accordingly 
    [self addCursorRect:viewRect cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];

    viewRect = [self.pMailImageView frame];
    [self addCursorRect:viewRect cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];

    viewRect = [self.pDialImageView frame];
    [self addCursorRect:viewRect cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];



}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)